# BigQuery Intraday Tables fail - GA360

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We've linked our GA360 to BQ. For a few days, it seems like that Intraday tables fail to be generated. Daily tables are showing there though.

Does anyone know what the reason might be?

Comment: hi, @alireza its better to explain in more detail for example what changes you did before this scenario occurred in order to help someone answer.

Comment: hi @NomiAli, We didn't make any changes there. We just don't see the Intraday tables!

Answer (score 0):

Analytics exports to BigQuery creates a daily table. The creation of the daily table based on `intraday` data can be delayed if:

- the amount of data to export is large
- errors occur during the processing or there is a general large load on the `Analytics -> BigQuery export`.

As it is said in the official documentation:

> After you link a project to BigQuery, the first daily export of events
> creates a corresponding dataset in the associated BigQuery project.
> Then, each day, raw event data for each linked app populates a new
> daily table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is streamed
> into a separate intraday BigQuery table in real-time.

This means that everyday collected data will be streamed to the `intraday` temporary table in BigQuery. That table collects all the data from the current day, which then are moved to its `appevents` permanent table at the end of the day. Intraday tables are not renamed/transferred to the daily tables. A new table is created for the daily export, and the temporary intraday table are deleted.

I recommend you to take a look for the following [Firebase post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html).

It could also happen that there is an error that occurs on Firebase site (outside the customer's control), feel free to fill in [support ticket](https://firebase.google.com/support).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Do you know at what point is 'too big'? Is there a row or size limit? We're experiencing the same issue...